# AdMob (Mobile Ads) in bottom sheet dialog error in android

Tags: android

anybody can help me in this, I made an App & I used a bottom sheet Dialog in the App, now I need to add ADMob to one of the rows & I did the xml part, but in the activity page related to the bottom sheet I still have an error.
[image]

and here is the Java code for the bottom sheet with the AdMob part.... please advise

```
    private BottomSheetListener mListener;
    private TextView aboutSheet;
    private ImageView DuctLiteImage, DuctFullImage, ourAppArrow;
    private CardView aboutUsCard, storeGoogleCard, ductLiteCard, ductFullCard, recommendedCard, contactUsCard, ourApps;
    private TextView ductSizerLite, ductSizerFull, storeGoogle, recommendedStore, contactUs;
    LinearLayout ductLiteLayout, ductFullLayout;
    AdView mAdView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, container, false);
        CardView aboutUsCard = v.findViewById(R.id.about_us_card);
        CardView storeGoogleCard = v.findViewById(R.id.store_card);
        CardView ductLiteCard=v.findViewById(R.id.duct_lite_card);
        CardView ductFullCard=v.findViewById(R.id.duct_full_card);
        CardView recommendedCard=v.findViewById(R.id.recommended_card);
        CardView contactUsCard=v.findViewById(R.id.conract_us_card);
        CardView ourApps=v.findViewById(R.id.our_apps_card);
        LinearLayout ductLiteLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.lite_Linear);
        LinearLayout ductFullLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.full_layout);
        ImageView  ourAppArrow = v.findViewById(R.id.ourapp_arrow);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` instead of `this` in your code or pass out a `Context` from your parent Activity.